# Drawing and updating line between two images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently have two UIImageViews which can be dragged to move them across the screen:

```
- (void)panWasRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {
    UIView *draggedView = panner.view;
    CGPoint offset = [panner translationInView:draggedView.superview];
    CGPoint center = draggedView.center;
    draggedView.center = CGPointMake(center.x + offset.x, center.y + offset.y);
    [panner setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:draggedView.superview];
}

- (void)panWasRecognized2:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner2 {
    UIView *draggedView = panner2.view;
    CGPoint offset = [panner2 translationInView:draggedView.superview];
    CGPoint center = draggedView.center;
    draggedView.center = CGPointMake(center.x + offset.x, center.y + offset.y);
    [panner2 setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:draggedView.superview];
}
```

However I was not sure how I would do the next step which was going to be drawing a line between the two centres of UIImageViews being constantly updated as the images are moved by the user. I roughly know how to draw a simple line from point to point, but is anyone able to suggest how to keep updating that line in sync with movement of the two images? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well it depends where you are doing the drawing; I assume the parent view of the `UIImageViews`?  In that case you can just tell the view to redraw using `setNeedsDisplay` (or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`) and then implement the drawing in `drawRect:`.

Comment: Do you want a connector line from one image centre to other ?

Comment: Yep, so simply a line stretching from the centre of first image to second image which can move according to the position of either images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it by subclassing the parent `UIView`. Just create a class and copy-paste the code for

**`DrawView.h`**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DrawView : UIView
-(void)refreshWithPointA:(CGPoint)pointA andPointB:(CGPoint)pointB;
@end
```

**`DrawView.m`**

```
#import "DrawView.h"

@interface DrawView()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *linePath;
@end

@implementation DrawView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}



-(void)refreshWithPointA:(CGPoint)pointA andPointB:(CGPoint)pointB{
    _linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [_linePath setLineWidth:2.0];
    [_linePath moveToPoint:pointA];
    [_linePath addLineToPoint:pointB];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    // Drawing code
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [_linePath stroke];
}


@end
```

Now simply change the parent UIView class on which you have added `UIImageView`. And assign tag `1` and `2` to two imageviews. And use the method below in your `pangesture selectors`

```
-(void)refreshLine{
    CGPoint centreA=[self.view viewWithTag:1].center;
    CGPoint centreB=[self.view viewWithTag:2].center;
    [self.drawView refreshWithPointA:centreA andPointB:centreB];
}
```

Put the method in both the gesture recognizers last line like below

```
- (void)panWasRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {
     //YOUR OLD CODE

     [self refreshLine];
}

- (void)panWasRecognized2:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {

     //YOUR OLD CODE

     [self refreshLine];
}
```

and as well where you are adding the UIImageViews, it will draw the lines immediately. Create an `IBOutlet` of your `UIView` too with new class assigned.

Thats it.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I understand most of your code but I have a few questions - firstly, after putting the code into my .h and .m files, I have got the error "no visible @interface for ... declares the selector..." for both initWithFrame and setNeedsDisplay. Also, I am not sure what you mean by assigning tags to imageViews and changing the parent UIView class. I'm sorry if these questions seem primitive, I am fairly new to programming :)

Comment: actually I seem to have solved most of the errors. The only thing that is not working right now is drawView, and I am not sure about the IBOutlet part.

Comment: You need to create an outlet of the view for which you have changed the class, to access the method of the DrawView. See here what I mean https://db.tt/TD5n3iYY

Comment: ah I see, this is what I have at the moment: http://oi61.tinypic.com/15yw7ys.jpg. I assume I need to subclass the UIView, so how would I do that?

Comment: You just need to copy paste the code above for `DrawView` and change the class of the View in storyboard the way described here http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cRzY33W3ofc/TzOfObr1rII/AAAAAAAAAaY/i4tkY6qbcKc/s1600/ViewController3.jpg

Answer (score 2):

For example u can do this by subclassing the `UIView` and override `drawRect` method
sample code, in subclassed `UIView` u can do something like below

```
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
     // Initialization code
     UIImageView *imgViewOne = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
     imgViewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //imageview 1

     UIImageView *imgViewTwo = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 100)];
     imgViewTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //imageview 2

     UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];
     [imgViewOne addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

     UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized2:)];
     [imgViewTwo addGestureRecognizer:panGesture2];

     imgViewOne.tag = 100;
     imgViewTwo.tag = 200;

     imgViewTwo.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     imgViewOne.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

     [self addSubview:imgViewOne];
     [self addSubview:imgViewTwo];

  }
  return self;
}


- (void)panWasRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner
{
   UIView *draggedView = panner.view;
   CGPoint offset = [panner translationInView:draggedView.superview];
   CGPoint center = draggedView.center;
   draggedView.center = CGPointMake(center.x + offset.x, center.y + offset.y);
   [panner setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:draggedView.superview];
   [self setNeedsDisplay];//update the drawing
}

- (void)panWasRecognized2:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner2
{
   UIView *draggedView = panner2.view;
   CGPoint offset = [panner2 translationInView:draggedView.superview];
   CGPoint center = draggedView.center;
   draggedView.center = CGPointMake(center.x + offset.x, center.y + offset.y);
   [panner2 setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:draggedView.superview];
   [self setNeedsDisplay]; //update the drawing

}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.  
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);//clear drawing

   UIImageView *imgView1 = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:100];
   UIImageView *imgView2 = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:200];

   CGPoint center1 = imgView1.center;
   CGPoint center2 = imgView2.center;

   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);//set background white color
   CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);


   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor); //set the color of the line
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5); //set width of line

   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center1.x,center1.y); //start at this point
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center2.x,center2.y); //draw to this point

   CGContextClosePath(context);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
 }


 @end
```

in view controller just add the this view

```
 #import "MyView.h" //import this custom view


 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    MyView *view = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:view]; //add it to view controller's view
   }
```

Comment: Is there a way of making this work on an already established UIViewController instead of creating a new View on top of it (e.g.. using UIImageViews in the controller instead of programmatically initialising them). This is what I have now :http://oi60.tinypic.com/ezn7ev.jpg but I need it to work on one layer with http://oi61.tinypic.com/15yw7ys.jpg